# Is there an efficient way to find two positive integers given their xor and product?

Tags: factoring

Is there an efficient way
to find two positive integers
given their bitwise exclusive or and product?

I saw this on quora, and wasn't able
to come up with a good solution.
Ideally,
I would like a
O(1) or O(number of bits) algorithm

An obvious way 
is to factor the product,
using the xor to
bound the factors,
and seeing which factors
when xored
give the desired xor.

Also,
I'm not sure what tags
this should use besides factoring.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by 'xor'. I assume you mean the xor of their binary expressions, but we don't assume that on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Done. Good point.